# Replacing GUID in Kusto

Tags: regexp-replace, azure-data-explorer, kql

How can I replace all GUID's in a Kusto query with no value.

e.g.

my data looks like

/page/1d58e797-a905-403f-ebd9-27ccf3f1d2cd/user/4d58e797-a905-403f-ebd9-27ccf3f1d2c3

and I want

/page//user/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/replacefunction) function. Also, you can test regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/R8fVOs/1).

```
let input = '/page/1d58e797-a905-403f-ebd9-27ccf3f1d2cd/user/4d58e797-a905-403f-ebd9-27ccf3f1d2c3';
let rx = '[({]?[a-fA-F0-9]{8}[-]?([a-fA-F0-9]{4}[-]?){3}[a-fA-F0-9]{12}[})]?';
print replace(rx, '', input);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the below regex It will remove guid (8-4-4-4-12) in url

```
 let regex =/(\/[\w]{8}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{12})(\b|\/)/g
```

Comment: The question refers to KQL (Kusto Query Language)

Comment: You can use regex, but in KQL syntax (replace() function)